# When i try to compile my code I get an error saying 'undefined reference to pow()' even when linking with '-lm'

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm making a user-defined function inside of my program and when I try to use the `pow` function, the compiler gives me an error and says that there is an `undefined reference to pow()`. I've seen similar problems to this and the solution was to add `-lm` when I compile. I've done this and yet it still has the problem. Its only happened on my user-defined functions because it worked before when I just put the `pow` in the `main` function of my code. It also works if the exponent is `2` instead of `0.5`. Thank you for you help.

```
 #include<math.h>

 float standard_deviation (float variance) {

       float deviation = 0.0;
       deviation = pow(variance, 0.5);

       return deviation;
 } /* mean */


 float standard_error (float standard_deviation, int number_of_elements) {

     return standard_deviation / pow(number_of_elements, 0.5);

 } /* mean */
```

Comment: How do you build your program? From the command line? Where on the command line did you put `-lm`? Because order matter, the libraries need to be after source/object files.

Comment: Show the (individual) command(s) you use to compile and link. Better yet, make a fully-blown standalone example that shows this problem.

Comment: @Steven Carlisle, Which is you compiler?

Comment: I'm using putty which is provided by my university. It uses a make file in unix. I type make big_statistics_function and then hit enter. That command compiles the code based on the makefile  which looks like this: big_statistics_funtion: big_statistics_function.c
                gcc -o big_statistics_funtion big_statistics_function.c
                -lm

Comment: Steven, please [edit] your question to include your compilation command (or Makefile fragment) - it's easily lost amongst the comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float standard_deviation (float variance)
{
  float deviation = 0.0;
  deviation = pow(variance, 0.5);
  return deviation;
} /* mean */

float standard_error (float standard_deviation, int number_of_elements)
{
  return standard_deviation / pow(number_of_elements, 0.5);
} /* mean */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf ("%f\n", standard_deviation (1.0));
        return 0;
}
```

compiles without any problems when invoked like this:

```
gcc test10.c -o test10 -lm
```

If you are compiling .c to .o files first, you only need -lm at the final linking stage generating the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `float` instead of `double`, you should use `powf`.

```
deviation = powf(variance, 0.5f);
return standard_deviation / powf((float)number_of_elements, 0.5f);
```

Compile with `-lm`.

Comment: so I tried changing it to powf and then it just said that it had an undefined reference to powf

Comment: @StevenCarlisle did you compile with `-lm` ?

Comment: big_statistics_funtion: big_statistics_function.c
                gcc -o big_statistics_funtion big_statistics_function.c
                -lm
I have the -lm. I don't know if thats what you mean or not but its the thing that we've done in the class everytime with no problems.

Comment: @StevenCarlisle: So you seem to be using a makefile. Dare to show it? Any ways search `LDFLAGS` inside the makefile and add the `-lm` there.

Comment: I have the -lm in the make file for this program and every other one because its the way that the class taught. This is what is looks like: big_statistics_funtion: big_statistics_function.c
                gcc -o big_statistics_funtion big_statistics_function.c
                -lm